# ROS-enabled golf-car?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite interested to build a ROS-enabled golf-car, perhaps this is one step towards autonomous vehicle. I did a search and only found Grizzly from clearpath robotics is quite similar to an autonomous vehicle, but Husky can't carry passengers. My question is, is there any ros-enabled golf-car available in the market, or sth. similar?  Ideas are welcome.. Thanks a Lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76057/ros-enabled-golf-car?/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-03**:
Clearpath also has the grizzly, which might fit your size a bit better.

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-03**:
Yes, What I mean is Grizzly, not husky. In fact, Husky is even smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Marvin, a real car:

http://www.ros.org/news/2010/03/robots-using-ros-marvin-autonomous-car.html

Marti, another car:

http://www.swri.org/4org/d10/msd/automation/ros-autonomous.htm

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-03**:
Unfortunately, a car is out of my reach at the moment... Perhaps, sth. that doesn't need a license plate